# Visual Studio - How to handle Project Property Changes

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, vspackage

I have a `UserControl` that has to read a string (an URL) from a file **At Design Time**. So I made a `VSPackage` that exposes a Menu Command in the Visual Studio IDE; clicking on the command the user will be able to provide the URL via a WPF window and save this value to a file pressing Ok.

The `UserControl` reads the file on the `ControlLoaded` event and gets the URL property. Now...if the user changes the URL value again using the `VSPackage` Window, *how can I intercept this property change?* Is there a way to access `VSPackage` properties from `UserControl` code?

Thanks

Comment: There are better ways to extend design-time functionality of of a `WPF` control or component, instead of creating an extension for such purpose: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546938(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Yes, I agree but in this case I have to set a "project" setting; all the controls of a certain type will automatically read this setting. I cannot set each object with the same parameter.